# s#arp castle injection

Tags: castle-windsor, s#arp-architecture

I have a soap web service in my web layer (s#arp architecture) which uses a service like this:

```
public ReportWebService(IReportService ReportService)
{
 Check.Require(ReportService != null, "ReportService may not be null");
 this.ReportService = ReportService;
}
```

Can someone please remind me how/where I configure the injection of the implementation for IReportService again?

Thanks.

Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The short answer is**: Just put ReportService into yourProject.ApplicationServices and it will be injected.

**The long answer is**: In yourProject.Web in Global.asax you will find the method InitializeServiceLocator(). This calls the static method AddComponents on ComponentRegistrar.

ComponentRegistrar is located in yourProject.web/CastleWindsor. In there you will find

```
public static void AddComponentsTo(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        AddGenericRepositoriesTo(container);
        AddCustomRepositoriesTo(container);
        AddApplicationServicesTo(container);

        container.AddComponent("validator",
            typeof(IValidator), typeof(Validator));
    }
```

If you look at AddApplicationServicesTo you can see that is registers all types in yourProject.ApplicationServices (.WithService.FirstInterface()):

```
private static void AddApplicationServicesTo(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        container.Register(
            AllTypes.Pick()
            .FromAssemblyNamed("NewittsStore.ApplicationServices")
            .WithService.FirstInterface());
    }
```

Comment: I tried something like this. Ok I have added: private static void AddWebTo(IWindsorContainer container)
        {
            container.Register(
                AllTypes.Pick()
                .FromAssemblyNamed("College.Web")
                .WithService.FirstInterface());
        } Not sure you should/could add a web service to the service layer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is from ComponentRegistrar.cs:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The add application services to.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="container">
    /// The container.
    /// </param>
    private static void AddApplicationServicesTo(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        container.Register(AllTypes.Pick().FromAssemblyNamed("MyAssembly.ApplicationServices").WithService.FirstInterface());
    }
```

and here is from the a service

```
    private readonly IDocumentManagementService _client;

    public DocumentService(IDocumentManagementService client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }
```

This should help you out.